# Chrome print preview cut in half on Android tablet and windows XP

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I'm having an issue on a project we are working on right now. 
Chrome on Android tablet and on Windows Desktop does not print the whole generated pages. The problem occurs randomly (1 time every 6/7 print preview) on Chrome (never on OSX Desktop...).

On Windows desktop, changing the zoom print parameter to 99% eliminates the problem (seems like it redraws the pages and eliminates the problem). 
The project is a simple HTML/CSS page generated by Symfony.

Still looking for a solution, any idea ? ...

[image]